# I faced this error after trying to install mongodb on ubuntu 16.10

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

When trying to install mongodb on ubuntu 16.10

When I type this:

```
$ sudo systemctl start mongodb
Failed to start mongodb.service: Unit mongodb.service is masked
```

I have followed all the steps on the following [link](http://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Answer (score 5):

The error tells you the service is masked, which means it isn't allowed to start. Run `sudo systemctl unmask mongodb` to unmask it.